# Make the whole gridLayoutWidget clickable

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following code which shows me 7 of the widgets in a history window of my application. Each widget has a name, icon and an address to a previously opened file. I want all widgets to be clickable and write a function which exactly knows which widget was clicked. I have no clue on how to make a whole widget act as a single clickable item.
This is my code for showing the widgets.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        
        for i in range (7):
            self.gridLayoutWidget = QWidget(self)
            self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(40, 40 + i * 60, 350, 40))

            self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
            self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.Label1 = QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
            self.Label1.setText("the name of the file")
            self.Label1.setFont(QFont('Arial', 14))

            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Label1, 0, 1, 1, 9)

            self.Label2 = QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
            self.Label2.setText("the address of the file")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Label2, 1, 1, 1, 9)

            self.im = QPixmap("img.ico")
            self.icon = QLabel()
            self.icon.setPixmap(self.im)

            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.icon , 0, 0, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is better to create a class that inherits from widget and implements the logic of the complex widget to avoid repetitive code that can cause problems (for example self.Label2 what does QLabel refer to? Does it refer to the first, the second, ...? , since it refers to the latter). On the other hand, that allows us to override the mouseReleaseEvent method, causing a signal to be emitted that later allows us to identify the widget using the sender method.

```py
class GridLayoutWidget(QWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.Label1 = QLabel(text="the name of the file", font=QFont("Arial", 14))

        self.Label2 = QLabel(text="the address of the file")
        self.icon = QLabel(pixmap=QPixmap("img.ico"))

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Label1, 0, 1, 1, 9)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Label2, 1, 1, 1, 9)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.icon, 0, 0, 2, 1)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.clicked.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        rect = QRect(40, 40, 350, 40)

        for i in range(7):
            widget = GridLayoutWidget(self)
            widget.setGeometry(rect.translated(0, 60 * i))
            widget.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def handle_clicked(self):
        widget = self.sender()
        print(widget)
```